# Quotes being escaped inside wp_editor when saved with wp_kses_post

Tags: wp-editor, escaping, wp-kses

Hi have a setting screen where I allow users to create HTML emails with the convenience of the editor they are already used to from posts and pages using wp_editor();

Everything seems to work fine except when I try to save with texts which are in quotes when the value returns it has the escaping, I know that's because wp_kses_post(); sanitizes the data but what if user wants to create an HTML email with quotes in it?

I know I could do a str_replace, but is there another way? Should I even be using wp_kses_post(); if I plan to allow quotes?

**wp_editor code:**

```
wp_nonce_field('tld_wcdpue_settings_nonce_action', 'tld_wcdpue_settings_nonce_field');

$tld_wcdpue_settings_email_content = get_option('tld_wcdpue_settings_email_content');

wp_editor( $tld_wcdpue_settings_email_content, 'tld_wcdpue_settings_wpeditor', array( 'wpautop' => false ) );
```

**wp_editor saving code:**

```
if( isset(//does authentication here) ){

update_option( 'tld_wcdpue_settings_email_content', wp_kses_post( $_POST['tld_wcdpue_settings_wpeditor'] ) );

}
```

When this gets saved to the DB it gets escaped so the return is:

[image]

I know I could simply do a str_replace but wouldn't that be defeating the purpose of wp_kses_post? Should I even be using it in this case? I also realize I am not escaping when pulling the data from the db, not sure how I should since I want HTML to render in the editor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wordpress always escapes quotes encountered in the super globals variables. It is 
done in https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_magic_quotes/

You will most likely want to strip it with `stripslashes` before saving it into the DB. something like

`update_option( 'tld_wcdpue_settings_email_content', wp_kses_post( stripslashes($_POST['tld_wcdpue_settings_wpeditor'] ) ));`

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you need to use `wp_kses_post()`.

`update_option()` runs `sanitize_option()` which should take care of everything for you.

Test it and let me know what happens.

Comment: It turns out I would need wp_kses_post, because if I didn't then users would be able to add JS to the db when only HTML should be allowed.